# hide profile picture for google voice messages

Tags: security, google-voice, profiles

I have migrated my primary phone number to a google voice number. It caused some surprise to see my profile picture appear next to my message on someone else's phone. This number is used in a wide array of contexts and would like it to be as anonymous as possible. Is there a way to uncouple google voice VoIP activity from google profile information?